# Flask Bootstrap Alerts and Close Button not displaying correctly

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get bootstraps alerts working but I think I missing something. Here is a cut down version of my code that displays the issues...

**Python File**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def settings() -> None:
    return render_template('settings.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**HTML Template**

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> 
</button>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

When running this the alert doesn't display. When the `fade` class is removed it does display. I strongly suspect that the alert immediately fades upon page load but I can't figure out why.

The second issue is that the `btn-close` class doesn't display a lovely X but a square grey button. Why doesn't this load the bootstrap image? This is also the case when I remove the `<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">` from the alert and have it display in the content in its own right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issues was the use of an older [Flask-Bootstrap](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/) which only support Bootstrap 2 or 3. The components that I wanted to use were not available in these versions.

I found a couple of options:

**Use a native Bootstrap setup:**

- Follow the [Get Started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/) in setting up Bootstrap on the site. For convivence copy the Bootstrap’s CSS and JS section into a file called `base.html` and add it to all the required html pages. For example...

`base.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>

    <br/>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Use Bootstrap-Flask**

- [Bootstrap-Flask](https://bootstrap-flask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) - Bootstrap 4 & 5 helper for your Flask projects.
- [Migrate from Flask-Bootstrap](https://bootstrap-flask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrate/)